# Problems Installing Dukto?

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, 17.04

I can't seem to follow the tutorials for Dukto (A file transfer program, an alternative to Wi-fi Direct), as the command `sudo apt install dukto` returns `E: Unable to locate package dukto`
 Does this package still exist? Every tutorial on the subject seems to include an install command for this package. I'm using Kubuntu 17.04, so maybe this has something to do with it? I don't know if 17.04 is compatible with 16.04 packages, which I believe duckto is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dukto is not in the regular Ubuntu repositories.

Download it at the home page at http://www.msec.it/blog/?page_id=11

The direct Ubuntu download is at https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:colomboem&package=dukto

**Update #1:**

Did you follow these instructions?

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dukto.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dukto
```

If that didn't work, then do this...

Download the file here...

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04/amd64/dukto_6.0-1_amd64.deb

And assuming that the .deb file went to your Downloads folder, install it with...

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/dukto_6.0-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Curious, I followed the instructions, and still got the same error message.

Comment: @SarahSzabo please see the update to my answer. Report back.

Comment: Not sure why the `.deb` worked, but the command line version didn't.

Comment: @SarahSzabo show me `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dukto.list`.

Comment: `deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04/ /
`

Comment: @SarahSzabo looks fine. I don't know why the first method didn't work for you, unless the product name was different... ie:dukto_6.0-1. You could look in Synaptic to confirm that.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 I get a bunch of missing dependencies when I try to install the deb file. I tried to install the dependencies, but then I get other missing dependencies.. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late but you can install it from snap

[Install Dukto](https://snapcraft.io/install/dukto/ubuntu)

**Enable Snapd**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

**Install dukto**

```
sudo snap install dukto
```